# Blurry screen when using a tv screen

Tags: resolution, hdmi, dvi

I have a bit of a problem. My dad says I could have the TV in one of our cottages, its a Sony Bravia 1080. I dont know what the exact size is. When I used the hdmi cable, the screen was kind of blurry, I couldnt even tell the difference between 'm and n'. So i used the DVI cable(blue adapter) and now my max resolution is 1360 x 768 instead of 1920 x 1080.

My system specs:

Intel Core i7 2600k 3.4GHZ

nVidia GTX 650

8 gig ddr3 1600mhz

Is there a way I can sort this out?

Thanks  in advance :)

Comment: We need the exact model in order to determine the max support resolution.

Comment: I have an older Samsung 23" SyncMaster which runs on 1920 x 1080 perfectly. The Sony is way bigger than the Samsung. With this horrible resolution, everything looks so big and messy!

Comment: We need the model, the size of the television, isn't all that important.